# Implementing MediatR 12

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, mediatr

I have a problem using MediatR 12. I configure during startup in this way, MediatR maps my controller but does not map the handler. This is my code:

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            AddSwagger(services);
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddScoped<UsuarioRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<CategoriaRepository>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<ACVOBContext>(options=> options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
        }
```

My Controller:

```
 [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Get user by ID")]
        [HttpGet("{userId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsuarioById(long userId)
        {
            var request = new GetUserByIdQuery() { UserID = userId };
            var response  = await _mediator.Send(request);
            return this.Ok(response);

        }
```

My Handler:

```
public class GetUserByIdQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetUserByIdQuery, UserResponse>
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public GetUserByIdQueryHandler(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public async Task<UserResponse> Handle(GetUserByIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _userService.GetUserById(request.UserID);
        }
    }
```

The error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type
 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[ACVOB.Application.Features.User.Queries.GetUserByIdQuery,ACVOB.Domain.User.Queries.UserResponse]'
 has been registered.
```

I tried different ways in Startup but none work. I saw in another post that the problem could be the interface, but I couldn't solve it either.

Comment: Please post on [es.so]

Comment: You forgot to translate the title.

Comment: Is your handler located in the same project as your startup/program.cs?

Answer (score 1):

after searching in different posts I found the problem. I was missing registering my IRequestHandler interface. I leave you my solution:

Sturtup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    AddSwagger(services);
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddScoped<UsuarioRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<CategoriaRepository>();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserService), typeof(UserService));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRequestHandler<GetUserByIdQuery, UserResponse>), typeof(GetUserByIdQueryHandler));
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddDbContext<ACVOBContext>(options=> options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    //services.AddAutoMapperConfiguration();
    //services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
}
```